# Traffic forwarding

Tags: linux, bash, http, tcp, multicast

I have an application that sends HTTP GET requests and receives answers from some web server.
Is it possible to accomplish following: read the incoming data on on wire on port 80 using Linux commands (no code) and forward it to multicast group or just any upd port. Tried to do it with nc, no success.
I am aware it can be easily done on application level, I am trying to avoid unnecessary latency on bringing the data up to application level and then putting it down to wire. Time is very crucial here.
Thanks all.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/308221/how-to-make-tcpdump-or-other-tool-to-actually-dump-tcp-stream

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tcpflow](http://www.circlemud.org/jelson/software/tcpflow/) to capture the actual data in a TCP stream.  For example I can start:

```
sudo tcpflow -C -v -i eth0 "tcp src port 80"
```

Then for example if I run `curl google.com` in another window, then `tcpflow` dumps the TCP stream.

You can then pipe this output to [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) to send it to a UDP socket.

UDP listener:

```
socat -u UDP-RECV:5555 STDOUT
```

Pipe the `tcpflow` output to this UPD listener:

```
sudo tcpflow -C -v -i eth0 "tcp src port 80" | socat STDIN UDP-SENDTO:localhost:5555
```

Bear in mind that TCP and UDP are quite different protocols, and thus have quite different use-cases.  TCP is stream-oriented, whereas UDP is datagram-oriented.  Trying to stuff a stream over a datagram-oriented socket will at best be unreliable.

Also while you may be able to get the above to work, I'm not sure how much performance gain you'll actually see.  No matter what happens, TCP stream reassembly **must** happen and the kernel will generally do this very efficiently.  Unlikely that `tcpflow` will do this any better than the kernel.